# In Magento 2.2.5, Update the cart items with custom options

Tags: cart, addtocart, magento-2.2.5, edit

In Magento 2.2.5, I want to update the cart products with custom options.

While adding to cart, It is added correctly and updated in `quote_item_option` table. While updating only `qty` is updated, other than no other custom options are not updated.

Any way to achieve this.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Can you anyone help us to sort out this?

Comment: Could you get solution?

Comment: were you able to find solution